# Issue exporting MySQL database using XAMPP Control Panel v3.3.0

Tags: mysql, database, server, xampp

I am encountering an issue while trying to export an existing database from MySQL using XAMPP Control Panel version 3.3.0. After initiating the export process, the resulting file does not contain the database information as expected. Instead, it contains the following error code:

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<h1>Error</h1>
<p><strong>SQL Query:</strong> <a href="#" class="copyQueryBtn" data-text="SET time_zone = &quot;+00:00&quot;">Copy</a>
<a href="index.php?route=/database/sql&sql_query=SET+time_zone+%3D+%22%2B00%3A00%22&show_query=1&db=getion_biblio"><span class="text-nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit">&nbsp;Edit</span></a></p>
<p>
<code class="sql"><pre>
SET time_zone = &quot;+00:00&quot;
</pre></code>
</p>
<p>
<strong>MySQL responded:</strong> <a href="./url.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F8.0%2Fen%2Fserver-error-reference.html" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help"></a>
</p>
<code>#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: &#039;+00:00&#039;</code><br>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any guidance or insights from the developer community on how to resolve this problem. It seems that the issue is related to the time zone, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: What application are you using to do the export? phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @aldemarcalazans Yes  i use phpMyAdmin

Comment: Does it happen when you try to export other databases (example: phpmyadmin database, mysql database)?

Comment: There is an article about this situation here: https://database.guide/fix-error-1298-hy000-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone-in-mysql/#:~:text=If%20you're%20getting%20error,configured%20for%20named%20time%20zones.

Comment: @aldemarcalazans Maybe you don't understand my problem